# PostgreSQL: Get PID of a query via dblink before it finishes

Tags: postgresql, pid, dblink

I want to make monitoring for my queries which I am sending via dblink `dblink_send_query`, and thus I need it's **PID** so I can search for it in pg tables. 
But so far I was only able to get **PID** after dblink finishes via returning value `pg_backend_pid()` or doing it quite clumsy by getting it from pg_stat_activity by searching with query string, which doesn't account for multiple same queries or is really not ideal for queries that are text long.

So how can I get PID for this before it finishes?

```
select dblink_send_query('cn1', 'select pg_sleep(60)');
select dblink_send_query('cn2', 'select pg_sleep(60)');
select dblink_send_query('cn3', 'select pg_sleep(60)');
```

> PostgreSQL 11.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
>   20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backend process ID will stay the same for the whole life of the dblink connection.

So when you open the connection, run `SELECT pg_backend_pid()` first and save the result in a data structure where it is associated with the connection. Then you can just query that data structure to get the backend process ID for that connection.

Comment: but the problem is that dblink create it's own connection so if I use SELECT pg_backend_pid() it will give me the current one not the one of the dblink, may you please show me how to do it in this example

Comment: do $$
begin
perform dblink_connect ('cn1', 'fdw_cdc');        
perform dblink_connect ('cn2', 'fdw_cdc');
perform dblink_connect ('cn3', 'fdw_cdc');

perform dblink_send_query('cn1', 'select pg_sleep(60)');
perform dblink_send_query('cn2', 'select pg_sleep(60)');
perform dblink_send_query('cn3', 'select pg_sleep(60)');

perform pg_sleep(60);

perform dblink_disconnect ('cn1');
perform dblink_disconnect ('cn2');
perform dblink_disconnect ('cn3');
end $$

Comment: No. `perform dblink_connect ('cn1', 'fdw_cdc');`, then `SELECT dblink_send_query('cn1', 'select pg_backend_pid()')` and memorize the result for later.

Comment: ok I see what you mean, but there is a problem, if I use dblink connection in function to get me pid I can't use that connection anymore because when I try to send my query after I get pid I get error "could not send query: another command is already in progress" see here https://www.codepile.net/pile/VdNJKndb

Comment: I forgot... Use `dblink_exec` for that query to get synchronous execution.

Comment: but I use this one because of the parallel possibilities to utilize our multi-core  server, and the whole point of my monitoring is to make sure it runs smoothly... so is there a way to get PID for these asynchronous dblinks?

Comment: Why? That query will be super fast, certainly faster than establishing the connection. Consider it part of the process of establishing a dblink connection.

Comment: ah you meant `dblink_exec` only for getting the PID, get it :) .... but only thing it should be `dblink` not `dblink_exec` because it will get an error "statement returning results not allowed" ... but thank you very much for the help, now it works

Comment: Right, sorry for mixing up the functions.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. I used below approach to solve the same.

```
select dblink_connect('cn1',*connectionstring*);
select pid from dblink('cn1', 'select pg_backend_pid()') as (pid integer);
select dblink_send_query('cn2', 'select pg_sleep(60)');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it